# Embedded html within while-loop to display result based on what data is returned

Tags: php, sql, loops, mysqli, while-loop

**Hi Friends**

The code I've presented displays data (moduleID & moduleName) associated with a log in user. Presently it shows specific html code associated with a moduleID that should be displayed on the screen when the user logs in. I want to implement a way to iterate through the values (Possibly if-else statement within loop) in order the specific html code i have presented to be shown when a user has one or many moduleID's attached to them.

**Here is my homepageDemo.php**

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    //including the database connection file
    include 'config.php';

    $cuserID= $_SESSION['userID'];

    //fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
    //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT m.moduleID, m.moduleName
    FROM modules m
    JOIN courses c ON m.courseID = c.courseID
    JOIN usersDemo u ON c.courseID = u.courseID
    WHERE userID = '$cuserID'"); // using mysqli_query instead



            //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
                echo "

        <div id='loader-wrapper'>
            <div id='loader'><div id='loader1'> 
              </div> 
              </div>
        <p><a  onclick='IS4439Function()'>IS4437</a></p>
        </div>

        ";

            }
            ?>
```

**Here is the html code attached to the moduleID of IS4437**

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
            <div id="loader"><div id="loader1"> 
              </div> 
              </div>
        <p><a  onclick="IS4439Function()">IS4437</a></p>
        </div>
```

**Here is the html code attached to the moduleID of IS4408**

```
<div id="loader-wrapper1">
            <div id="loader"><div id="loader1"> 
              </div> 
              </div>
        <p><a onclick="IS4408Function()">IS4408</a></p>
        </div>
```

---

### EDIT

So as I've mentioned the problem i'm currently having, these are the different methods I've already tried.

Originally before embedding the html into the while loop in the homepageDemo.PHP, I simply returned the moduleID & moduleName associated with logged in user as text

```
<?php
session_start();
//including the database connection file
include 'config.php';

$cuserID= $_SESSION['userID'];

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT m.moduleID, m.moduleName
FROM modules m
JOIN courses c ON m.courseID = c.courseID
JOIN usersDemo u ON c.courseID = u.courseID
WHERE userID = '$cuserID'"); // using mysqli_query instead



        //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>"."<a>".$res['moduleID']."</a>"."</td>";
            echo "<td>"."<a>".$res['moduleName']."</a>"."</td>";
        }
        ?>
```

Then I attempted to iterate through the values to return the html code associated with each individual moduleID

**SWITCH STATEMENT ATTEMPT:**

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     

        switch ($cuserID) {
            case 1:
                echo "

                <div id='loader-wrapper'>
                    <div id='loader'><div id='loader1'> 
                      </div> 
                      </div>
                <p><a  onclick='IS4439Function()'>IS4437</a></p>
                </div>

                ";
                break;
            case 2:
                echo "

                <div id='loader-wrapper'>
                    <div id='loader'><div id='loader1'> 
                      </div> 
                      </div>
                <p><a  onclick='IS4408Function()'>IS4408</a></p>
                </div>

                ";

                break;
            case 7:
                echo"

                <div id='loader-wrapper'>
```

**Functions called**

```
function IS4439Function() {
    {
      window.location.href = "global.php";
    }
}
function IS4408Function() {
    {
      window.location.href = "isStrategy.php";
    }
}
function IS4449Function() {
    {
      window.location.href = "webApp.php";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately neither were what I was trying to achieve. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to php and Instead of just down voting my post I would appreciate if you could tell me where i'm going wrong or if perhaps this is a duplicate and my question has already been asked then link the answer. Thank you

Comment: _"My question, is do you have any insight or coding example of how you would implement the while loop "_ SO isn't a place you come to get code examples or insight into how you should so something.

Comment: You're already getting the row data into `$res`.  Do some basic searching into how to access the results of a call to `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @Epodax Hi, I could be wrong but i was under the impression that this was a forum where people either asked questions based on developing problems they are having (to both help themselves and the next person who might be having the same problem) or posted questions with the intention or answering their own question in order to help those who need it.

Comment: It's a common misconception, [SO isn't a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362473/how-do-i-respond-to-assertions-that-stack-overflow-is-just-like-a-forum), it's a Q&A site with (to some) strict rules / guide lines on what goes and what doesn't go. It's more like "I have X problem, I have tried A and B and here is a minimal example of my code with the mentioned error" - Or some variant of that.

Comment: Please update your question with any additional information, do not put code in comments.  As you can see, it is rather unreadable.

Comment: Hi @Epodax I will update my question to do just that. Thank you

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ I have updated the question to show the extra code and also the switch case that I attempted to do what I need (unsuccessfully)

Comment: Okay, so let me frame it to you this way... You're trying to create an onclick that calls a moduleID-specific function, right? (even though you could probably have one function and just pass in the ID, but I won't get into that right now).  You've show that you already know how to get and output the moduleID.  So really all you need to do is combine your two examples.  Put the HTML into your loop, and just replace the hardcoded moduleID with the value from the PHP.

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ , thanks for your response. I have thought about putting the html into my loop and replacing the hardcoded moduleID with the value from PHP, my problem with this is the onclick is different for each moduleID and but this method will just present with the same on click for every moduleID.

Comment: Not if you replace the hardcoded value with the value with the value from `$res`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, and I'm not exactly sure where the disconnect is, but here you go.  You need to replace the hardcoded moduleID value (IS4439) with the value that you've already pull from the db.  Putting together what you already have, it really just comes down to concatenation.

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
    echo "
    <div id='loader-wrapper'>
        <div id='loader'><div id='loader1'> 
          </div> 
          </div>
    <p><a  onclick='" . $res['moduleID'] . "Function()'>". $res['moduleID'] . "</a></p>
    </div>
    ";
}
```

I would suggest though, that instead of calling different functions, you consider calling just one function, and passing in the moduleID as a parameter and then act accordingly within the function.

Based on your update, you would then have this...

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
?>
    <div id='loader-wrapper'>
        <div id='loader'><div id='loader1'> 
          </div> 
          </div>
    <p><a  onclick='redirectFunction("<?php echo $res['moduleID']; ?>");'><?php echo $res['moduleID']; ?></a></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

and your function would be...

```
function redirectFunction(moduleID)
{
    var newLocation = "";

    if(moduleID == "IS4439")
    {
        newLocation = "global.php";
    }
    else if(moduleID == "IS4408")
    {
        newLocation = "isStrategy.php";
    }
    else if(moduleID == "IS4449")
    {
        newLocation = "webApp.php";
    }

    window.location.href = newLocation;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Really appreciate your help. The only problem I have with this is that even though there's 3 moduleID's associated with the logged in user, it's only displaying the last moduleID!

Comment: Showing the last moduleID 3 times?  Or only showing one row, and that one row has the last moduleID?

Comment: Showing one row and that row has the last moduleID

Comment: That sounds like more of a problem with your data and/or query then.  Without knowing your data, I couldn't really speak to that.

Comment: If i use the answer you provided without my css, it shows each moduleID associated, although if I include my css, it only shows one row and has the last moduleID.

Comment: Well that's a completely different issue then and sounds like it is probably worth of it's own question.  You would want to provide the resulting HTML (copy/paste from view-source) and your CSS and then describe what's happening.

Comment: I feel like it's very nearly there but there's something minuscule that i'm missing..

Comment: That could be true, but the question here really had nothing to do with CSS, and asking a new question specific to the new problem could get you better answers than I may be able to provide (there are others on here who are far more proficient in CSS than I am).

Comment: Perfect, I'll do exactly that. Thank you Patrick for all of your help

Comment: No worries.  I'll take a look at your new question too, but like I said, there's a good chance that someone else might have more insight.  I'd suggest you essentially leave out all of this PHP/SQL stuff and just focus on the generated HTML, the CSS, and what is vs isn't visible.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll also on the suggestions given to me on how to structure my next question.